# Android Cursor IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, exception, cursor

I am using this library for a sectioned RecyclerView in my app: https://github.com/afollestad/sectioned-recyclerview

The sections are defined by the title/name of the objects to display. To populate data I'm fetching multiple Cursors from my database, returning them in a List:

```
List<String> sectionTitles = new ArrayList<>();
List<Cursor> sectionContent = new ArrayList<>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT title FROM table GROUP BY title", null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title));
            Cursor cursorContent = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE title = " + title, null);

            sectionTitles.add(title);
            sectionContent.add(cursorContent);

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
```

So for the section-titles I am using the first array, for the rows the second array. When I need data for a row in a section I call like this:

```
Cursor cursor = sectionContent.get(section);
cursor.moveToPosition(row);
cursor.getString(...);
```

Now the strange thing: I never closed one of the cursors in the ArrayList, but sometimes (1000 active users, 4-5 times per day) I am getting this Exception while calling `cursor.moveToPosition(section)`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery
```

Is there something wrong with storing Cursors in a List? Or am I missing something? Any help appreciated!

Comment: If you have too many open cursors then you will get an **_exception: unable to open database file (code 14);_**. I believe the number is somewhere around but over 1500. So that could be an issue that you may encounter, but not the above issue. Are you by any chance closing the database? I believe that that would close the cursors.

Comment: I guess there are about 50 cursors, so that would not be the problem. The database is a singleton, the connection is opened but never closed, so I don't see any issue either

Comment: Perhaps try extracting and populating a List with the underlying data from the cursor rather than the putting the cursor itself into a List. Saying that is `cursor.moveToPosition(section);` correcct? You appear to be getting the nth cursor (`section`) from the List of cursors and then moving to that same position (`section`) within the cursor.

Comment: My fault. I updated the code. It should be cursor.moveToPosition(row). But is is nothing wrong with my code, as it normally works well